# UINavigationController does not call viewDidLoad on pushed UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm facing an odd problem concerning pushing a UIViewController into a UINavigationController.
`CustomTableViewController` is a subclass of `UITableViewController`

```
CustomTableViewController* vc = [[CustomTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
UINavigationController *navVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
[self.view addSubview:navVC.view];
```

For some reason, the Navigation Controller is loaded and visible on screen but `viewDidLoad` is **never** called on `CustomTableViewController`.

Manually pushing the VC afterwards also does not work (still not loading the `vc`'s view)

- `[navVC pushViewController:vc animated:YES];`

However, the following methods **DO** call `viewDidLoad` on `vc`:

1. `[self.view addSubview:vc.view];`
2. `[self presentViewController:navVC animated:YES completion:nil];`
3. `[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];`

So I tend to believe that there is nothing wrong with the View Controller nor the Navigation Controller. However, I have no clue why the view is not being loaded. Manually forcing [vc view] will load the view but then the other view lifecycle methods are not called.

There is also nothing wrong with `CustomTableViewController`, as using `UITableViewController` itself also doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you adding the navVC view as a subView of self.view? I think you're not using it correctly. But yes, if what you are doing is correct (which I don't think it is) then @Bobj-C answer below will work.

Comment: I have a UITabBarController with a few dynamically added ViewControllers. Every ViewController holds one (in the future multiple) dynamic form(s), which can be a UITableViewController (with its own logic). This UITableViewController uses a UINavigationController for the add / edit logic behind it.

Comment: It sounds like you should probably be putting your `navVC` into the `viewControllers` array on your `UITabBarController`

Comment: If you want to have navigation controllers from a tab bar controller then you should have it as... UITabBarController - UINavigationController - ContentControllers. The Tab Bar then swaps between the NavigationControllers.

Comment: Not really, because in the future, it's possible that the top half of my VC is a TableView with Navigation Controller, but the bottom half is another form type.

Comment: So, what is `self` in the `[self.view addSubview]` call?

Comment: The VC with multiple childVC's in it (one of which is the TableView)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add it as child view controller

```
    [childController willMoveToParentViewController:rootViewController];
    [rootViewController addChildViewController:childController];
    [rootViewController.view addSubview:childController.view];
    [childController didMoveToParentViewController:rootViewController];
```

Hope this works

Comment: You actually don't need to call `willMoveToParentViewController:` here because `addChildViewController:` calls it automatically before adding the child view controller.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you're getting issues because it seems you are trying to make a custom container view controller.

[Read up on Apple's guide on custom container view controllers.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH11-SW12)

From the guide, here are some example methods to add and remove child view controllers:

**Swift 3.0:**

```
func display(contentController content: UIViewController) {
    addChildViewController(content)

    // Here, frameForContentController is just some function you define
    // that calculates and returns the frame of the content controller's view.
    content.view.frame = frameForContentController()

    view.addSubview(content.view)
    content.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}

func hide(contentController content: UIViewController) {
    content.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
    content.view.removeFromSuperview()
    content.removeFromParentViewController()
}
```

**Objective-C:**

```
- (void)displayContentController:(UIViewController *)content
{
   [self addChildViewController:content];

   // Here, [self frameForContentController] is just some method you define
   // that calculates and returns the frame of the content controller's view.
   content.view.frame = [self frameForContentController];

   [self.view addSubview:content.view];
   [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

- (void)hideContentController:(UIViewController *)content
{
   [content willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
   [content.view removeFromSuperview];
   [content removeFromParentViewController];
}
```